# DevExpress Multiple ListBox LostFocus Color effect

Tags: javascript, webforms, devexpress

So I have 2 listboxes, I'd like to turn each previously selected listbox index item to green.

Right now:

1. The listboxes starts with first index selected (I would like it to start out with no selection)
2. When jumping to a second listbox, it saves the first listboxes index and apply to the second listbox. (How to start fresh index on newly selected listbox? -- I tried resetting the index on `GotFocus` but it still doesn't work)

Example shown here: http://screencast.com/t/tFsYNJul

Here's the javascript:

```
var previousIndex = -1;
function OnInit(s, e) {
    previousIndex = s.GetSelectedIndex();
}

function OnSelectedIndexChanged(s, e) {
    if (previousIndex > -1) {
        s.GetItemRow(previousIndex).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        previousIndex = s.GetSelectedIndex();
    }
}
```

The markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <dx:ASPxListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="150px">

        <Items>
            <dx:ListEditItem Text="1" />
            <dx:ListEditItem Text="2" />
            <dx:ListEditItem Text="3" />
            <dx:ListEditItem Text="4" />
            <dx:ListEditItem Text="5" />
        </Items>
        <ItemStyle SelectedStyle-ForeColor="Black" SelectedStyle-BackColor="Yellow" />

        <ClientSideEvents Init="OnInit" LostFocus="function (s,e) { s.UnselectAll();  }" SelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
    </dx:ASPxListBox>

            <dx:ASPxListBox ID="ASPxListBox1" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="150px">

        <Items>
            <dx:ListEditItem Text="1" />
            <dx:ListEditItem Text="2" />
            <dx:ListEditItem Text="3" />
            <dx:ListEditItem Text="4" />
            <dx:ListEditItem Text="5" />
        </Items>
        <ItemStyle SelectedStyle-ForeColor="Black" SelectedStyle-BackColor="Yellow" />

        <ClientSideEvents Init="OnInit" LostFocus="function (s,e) { s.UnselectAll();  }"  SelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
    </dx:ASPxListBox>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will handle what's required properly:

```
function OnInit(s, e) {
    s.cpPreviousIndex = s.GetSelectedIndex();
}

function OnSelectedIndexChanged(s, e) {
    if (s.cpPreviousIndex > -1) {
        s.GetItemRow(s.cpPreviousIndex).style.backgroundColor = '#C0E0CE';
    }
    s.cpPreviousIndex = s.GetSelectedIndex();
}
```